# MINTEMP BED Fixed error when running consecutive print

Tags: prusa-i3, g-code, petg, prusaslicer, prusa-research

I am using "Pretty PETG" along with PrusaSlicer's consecutive print mode.

What I am noticing is that upon finishing the first print, the printer hits `MINTEMP BED Fixed`. I'm not sure if it's immediate because I let the prints run overnight but I assume the bed cools down and then the error is hit.

I'm just starting to learn G-code and my initial thought was there's an errant bed temperature instruction but the only `M140 S0` instructions I see are in the `end_gcode` and near the bottom of the file. Maybe there a `goto` in G-code which may be running after `M140 S0` which then causes the `MINTEMP BED` issue? Perhaps there's something else going on?

Comment: Maybe you could add the "end G-code"? Note that `goto` is not a G-code command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bed minimum temperature is defined in your configuration file, e.g.:

```
#define BED_MINTEMP        5
```

If the error is displayed, it means that the measured temperature drops below this level.

> What I am noticing is that upon finishing the first print

This could hint to a faulty heatbed connector where the connection is lost because the bed moves to the end positions (hard to say without seeing the end G-code).

Basically, you could have a connection to bed thermistor that is intermittently failing, or a bad bed thermistor. If connection is lost the temperature defaults to 0 °C or a lower setting.

Comment: yes, the issue turned out to be hardware and not gcode. there was a defect with the bed thermistor cable which only faults at the far back corner. my consecutive prints occur at these corners which is why I incorrectly suspected enabling consecutive printing as the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a hardware problem, namely the [heat bed thermistor cable](https://help.prusa3d.com/en/guide/4-heatbed-assembly_51736#52400).

To confirm this as the root cause, here's what you can try

- Reboot the printer
- Move the y axis around to make sure there is freedom of movement at both ends
- Jigger the thermistor cable around in multiple directions at multiple points on the cable

If you hit `BED MINTEMP` or `BED_MINTEMP fixed` then you have found a cable angle/position that causes the issue. You may need to replace the cable.

The issue could also happen at the connection with Einsey. If the wrapped cable going into Einsey is moved, the connection may be faulty.

- Ground yourself
- Open Einsy
- Ground yourself
- Reboot the printer
- Jigger the connection to Einsey

If you hit `BED MINTEMP` or `BED_MINTEMP fixed` then the connection is bad. Try unplugging and replugging the cable. Look at the connectors on both sides to try to determine if the source is the cable or Einsey. You may need to replace the cable or repair the Einsey connector.